# Scikit learn not importing in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
```

I have tried "pip install scikit-learn" and "pip install sklearn" so many times. It is showing reportMissingImports error

Comment: Are you using virtual environment? if yes activate it and try importing. Use pip list -l to list and verify the installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple python environments on your machine? Make sure you are using the one you have **sklearn** installed on.

You can use the following code to check the interpreter you are using, and then use the obtained path to install the sklearn package for the current environment.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

[image]

Or select the interpreter that has installed the **sklearn** package in the ***Select Interpreter*** panel(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Python:Select Interpreter**), and then create a new terminal activation environment.

[image]